# Compute the characteristic strip and conoid solution of a geometric PDE

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

This is a problem from Fritz John's *Partial Differential Equations*, which I'm working through for self-study.

> Given a family of spheres of radius $1$ with centers in the $xy$-plane $$u=G(x,y,\lambda,\mu) = \sqrt{1-(x-\lambda)^2+(y-\mu)^2)},$$ find the first order PDE they satisfy. Find all characteristic strips and give a geometric description. Find the conoid solution with vertex $(0,0,1/2)$. Find the integral surfaces through the line $x=s,y=0,z=1/2$.

I've found that $u_x = -(x-\lambda)u^{-1}$ and similarly for $y$, so I came up with the equation $$1-u^2(u_x^2+u_y^2)=u^2,$$ or equivalently, $F(x,y,z,p,q) = z^2(p^2+q^2+1)-1=0$. I also computed the characteristic equations, and I found them to be $$\frac{dx}{dt} = 2z^2p,\quad \frac{dy}{dt} = 2z^2q,\quad \frac{dz}{dt} = 2z^2(p^2+q^2) = 2(1-z^2)$$
$$\frac{dp}{dt} = -2pz(p^2+q^2+1),\quad \frac{dq}{dt} = -2qz(p^2+q^2+1).$$
I'm a little confused about finding all characteristic strips. Usually we are given initial data, so can I assume the initial curve has the form $\Gamma: (s,0,h(s))$, or does that not give all the characteristic strips? If I can take the initial date to of this form, I get the strip conditions to be $h'(s)=\phi(s)$ and $h(s)^2(\phi(s)^2+\psi(s)^2+1)=1$, where $p=\phi(s)$ and $q=\psi(s)$ at $t=0$. I get stuck in a muck of algebra at this point. I'm just now learning this material, so I'm unsure if what I've written down so far is even correct. Am I on the right path?

More generally, I don't understand enveloped surfaces very well, so I have no geometric intuition for what I've written down so far, and I don't know how to compute the conoid solution or integral surface. Could someone help me with the general setup for this part?

Answer (score 0):

Noting that by the equation$$p^2 + q^2 + 1 = z^{-2}$$the equations for $\dot{p}$ and $\dot{q}$ can be simplified. Furthermore, the equation for $z$ is independent from the rest, which means that we can solve for $z$ first, then for $p$ and $q$. Geometrically, our equation looks like an eikonal equation since it can be written as$$\left|\nabla u\right|^2 = u^{-2} - 1.$$This can be simplified by rewriting$$v = \sqrt{1 - u^2}$$as the equation$$\left|\nabla v\right|^2 = 1,$$which should suffice for giving us the geometric interpretation. The solution for the characteristics is$$z = \text{tanh}(s), \quad p = P\text{csch}(s), \quad q = Q\text{csch}(s), \quad x = X - P\text{sech}(s), \quad y = Y - Q\text{sech}(s),$$where$$s = 2(t - t_0)$$and $t_0$, $P$, $Q$, $X$, and $Y$ are constants.